# "The Application Was Unable to Start (0xc000007b)"

Tags: visual-studio-2019, exe

I have some problem about .exe files.

I writed a program using "visual studio 2019" (using MariaDB and Qt).
The exe file that compiled this program works normally on my PC. But when I run it on another PC, the error message below will be printed out.

"The Application Was Unable to Start (0xc000007b)"

In order to solve this problem, i tried something below as:

1. check xinput1_3.dll in C:\Windows\SysWOW64
2. install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable(x64) - 14.34.31931
3. install all runtimes using "All in One Runtimes"

However, the program still doesn't work.
If anyone can help me, I really appreciate it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88rx0.png)

I tried using DependencyWalker and provided DLL files at same path.
However, "The Application Was Unable to Start (0xc000007b)" is still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

That error code typically indicates you are missing one or more needed DLLs on the other computer. [Dependency Walker](https://dependencywalker.com) is an excellent tool for figuring out which one it is.

Download it on the other computer and use it to analyze your .exe there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
To address this issue, i first provided the required DLL file (libmariadb.dll, Qt5Cored.dll, Qt5Guid.dll, Qt5Widgetsd.dll) printed on the error message in the same path as the EXE file. 
And then, a simple "The Application Was Unable to Start (0xc000007b)" message was printed.
Even in this case, should i do the dependency check you mentioned again?

Comment: Yes, you likely missed one.

Comment: I tried using DependencyWalker and provided DLL files at same path.(I edited my manuscript) However, "The Application Was Unable to Start (0xc000007b)" is still occurs.
In this case, what else should i try?

Comment: Not sure - in my experience, missing DLLs are the problem and Dependency Walker will help you find them. Is it possible you are accidentally missing one in Dependency Walker? One other possible thing you can do is use Process Monitor (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) though I can't remember if it can capture dynamic linking activity.

Comment: thanks for your help :) because of your help, I can solved it. DependencyWalker is a useful tool! thank you again!